# How to refactor if-else bodies which perform similar action?

Tags: java

I had to program a class for binary trees' nodes in java, and more than method had the problem that the bodies of an if-else statement did pretty much the same thing. For example:

```
public void insert(int val) {
    if(val < key)
        if(left == null)
            left = new TreeNode(val, this);
        else
            left.insert(val);
    else
        if(right == null)
            right = new TreeNode(val, this);
        else
            right.insert(val);
}
```

Here code is repeated and I'd like to find a way to avoid this code repetition.
The only solution I've come up with, would work in C++, but not in java. That would be creating a reference on either 'left' or 'right' and than using that reference for the assignments.

To visualize it, something in the style:

```
public void insert(int val) {
    TreeNode direction = right;
    if(val < key)
        direction = left;

    if(direction == null)
 !!     direction = new TreeNode(val, this);  !!
    else
        direction.insert(val);
}
```

Where the line with leading and trailing !! wouldn't work because of the way reference semantics works in java. As said before, in C++, I'd simply create a reference on the left or right reference and work on that.

Is there any way to write this code in java without using the repetition of code?
Probably I'll encounter this problem again, in more complex situations, and I'd like to now how to solve it, since IMHO it brings to better maintainable code.

Comment: I wonder if this is "primarily opinon-based" (or perhaps "too broad")... (I'm noting the downvote on [Roland's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40959044/157247), which it seems to me can only be based on disagreeing with his conclusion nothing needs doing here, as his conclusion is not *factually* incorrect -- and so...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wouldn't say that it's opinion based, since I specifically asked if it's possible to refactor the code (implicitly asking how).
Roland answered the question, like you did, probably who downvoted him (not me) did it because his answer wasn't ad detailed as others.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I answered, I think it's this side of the line (not that it matters all that much :-) ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd create a reusable private method to isolate the logic that's repeated:

```
private TreeNode handleNode(TreeNode node, int val) {
    if(node == null)
        node = new TreeNode(val, this);
    else
        node.insert(val);
    return node;
}
```

then

```
public void insert(int val) {
    if(val < key)
        left = handleNode(left, val);
    else
        right = handleNode(right, val);
}
```

As you say, this particular example is fairly minimal, but this pattern is useful even here, and certainly when the logic being isolated/factored out is more complex.

If you're worried about the overhead of a method call, don't be. Method calls are really, really cheap. :-) And *if* this were a hotspot in the code, a modern JVM (like Oracle's) would identify that and inline the method call anyway, if it would be beneficial to do so.

Comment: (I'd also use `{}`. And `this.` on instance members. But those are matters of opinion...)

Answer (score 0):

Although the code looks repetitive, I would keep it as-is.

Since the two branches involve accessing different fields of the `Node` class, these accesses cannot be factored out (unless using reflection, which is not appropriate here).

The code is readable as-is. To ensure that it works correctly, write some unit tests. After that, probably nobody will ever need to look at this code again or step through it during a debugging session, so it doesn't really matter whether it is more elegant than your current version.